# Add a thousands separator with decimals

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to have a thousands separator with decimals which each 3 numbers separate them with a point (.) And if the amount has decimals do not remove the comma (,)

I have this method which does not work at all well.

```
export function formatAmount(object)
{
    let format = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-VE', { maximumFractionDigits: 10 });
    return format.format(object);
}
```

With this function if I pass a value for example

```
3253,55 -> 3253,55
10000 -> 10.000
25000,55 -> 25.000,55
15000,5421 -> 15.000,5421
```

Basically it works well if the amount of thousands has at least 5 figures, with 4 it does not make the separation with the point.
And I need the result to be the following

```
3253,55 -> 3.253,55
1000 -> 1.000
50000,20 -> 50.000,20
15000,5421 -> 15.000,5421
```

I don't know how to add the separator with 4 digits without affecting the decimals.

I found this possible solution in other questions

```
String(num).replace(/(?<!\..*)(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g, '$1.')
```

But this does not work for me because it transforms the comma (,) of the decimals into a point (.)

```
3253,50 -> 3.253.50
```

How do I get the result I need, to separate the thousands with points without being affected by the decimal point?

Comment: Use language code "de" instead: `(1000).toLocaleString('de', { minimumFractionDigits: 3, maximumFractionDigits: 3})` gives "1,000.000".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
const formatNumber = (number) => {
  const value = number + '';
  const list = value.split('.');
  const prefix = list[0].charAt(0) === '-' ? '-' : '';
  let num = prefix ? list[0].slice(1) : list[0];
  let result = '';
  while (num.length > 3) {
    result = `,${num.slice(-3)}${result}`;
    num = num.slice(0, num.length - 3);
  }
  if (num) {
    result = num + result;
  }
  return `${prefix}${result}${list[1] ? `.${list[1]}` : ''}`;
};

console.log(formatNumber(3253.55));
console.log(formatNumber(50000.20));
```